# 403 as HTTP error code when login to DocuSign

Tags: docusignapi

I'm using a [legacy service integration](https://docs.docusign.com/esign/guide/authentication/legacy_auth.html) with DocuSign (through custom X-DocuSign-Authentication header attribute) together with DocuSign SDK and I'm always receiving 403 as a HTTP error code from some of my platforms when trying to login to https://demo.docusign.net/restapi.

Below are some details regarding the response I've got:

- response code=403
- response headers={X-Cache=[MISS from squid.local], Server=[squid/3.1.23], Connection=[keep-alive], X-Squid-Error=[ERR_ACCESS_DENIED 0], Date=[Mon, 30 Apr 2018 07:21:00 GMT], Via=[1.0 squid.local (squid/3.1.23)], X-Cache-Lookup=[NONE from squid.local:3128], Vary=[Accept-Language], Content-Length=[3245], Mime-Version=[1.0], Content-Language=[en], Content-Type=[text/html]}

  - response body=

The same code with exactly the same credentials (Integrator key, user name and password) works perfectly on another platform.

So, I'm wondering what can be the reason?

Comment: Can you confirm that the 403 isn't caused by Squid?  It's not clear whether the 403 is coming from DocuSign or from your proxy.

Comment: Thank you for your response. Indeed we are using proxy on the that problem platform - I will double check its configuration.

Comment: Thank you for the hint, indeed the problem was related to proxy  (more precisely to the firewall configuration).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you behind a corporate firewall? I too was having the same issue so I added a proxy and the issue was resolved.

```js
            WebProxy webProxy = new WebProxy("http://[IP]:[PORT]", true)
            {
                UseDefaultCredentials = false,
                Credentials = new NetworkCredential("[domain]%5C[userid]", "[password]")
            };
```

Comment: Where did you use the webProxy variable in your code ?

Answer (score 0):

The issue is related to the firewall configuration.